# How to add OID datatype in rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration

I have following migration

```
class MigrationName < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def up
    create_table :my_table_1, if_not_exists: true do |t|
      t.string :key, null: false, annotations: { is_pi: false }
      t.string :value, null: false, annotations: { is_pi: false }
    end

    create_table :my_table_2, primary_key: :id, if_not_exists: true do |t|
      t.bigint :col1, null: false, annotations: { is_pi: false }
      t.string :col2, null: false, annotations: { is_pi: false }
      t.string :col3, null: false, annotations: { is_pi: false }
      t.datetime :deleted_at, annotations: { is_pi: false }
    end

    
 end

  def down
    drop_table :my_table_1, if_exists: true
    drop_table :my_table_2, if_exists: true
  end
end
```

Now I want to add a new table which has few columns of type `oid`. I did some googling and i couldn't find a direct mapping of OID to rails type. What would be best way to do so.

My target db is PostgresSQL12

Comment: See the documentation for [Object Identifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html). "*The oid type is currently implemented as an unsigned four-byte integer.*"

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find rail specific way to do usnigned int (without adding extra gems). I think i should be okay if i use `bigint`. thoughts?

Comment: I do not know Rail, but a *bigint* is a 64bit integer. So that should be ok. The only guard would be to make sure it is never negative; so perhaps use an absolute value function.